# Geth ran fine, but suddenly it's stuck and don't know the reason why

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm running geth rinkeby at my Macbook. My geth version is like this.

```
Geth
Version: 1.10.3-stable
Architecture: amd64
Go Version: go1.16.3
Operating System: darwin
```

It finished syncing and ran fine with receiving blocks. It ran well almost 2 months. But it's stuck now and I don't know why it's suddenly stucked. I ran geth rinkeby with below command.

```
geth --rinkeby --http --http.addr 0.0.0.0 --http.api eth,net,web3,personal,txpool,admin --ws --ws.addr 0.0.0.0 --ws.origins="*" --ws.api personal,admin,eth,net,web3,txpool,debug --allow-insecure-unlock --syncmode fast --cache 2048 --maxpeers 100 2>> ./logs/geth.log
```

And my geth log looks like below.

```
INFO [07-08|10:27:18.158] Imported new chain segment               blocks=1     txs=13   mgas=0.874   elapsed=15.973ms    mgasps=54.718   number=8,897,987 hash=d2df74..48ba4e dirty=496.76MiB
INFO [07-08|10:27:18.160] Unindexed transactions                   blocks=1     txs=6    tail=6,547,988 elapsed=2.467ms
INFO [07-08|10:27:21.284] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=5  static=1
INFO [07-08|10:27:31.286] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=5  static=1
INFO [07-08|10:27:41.286] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=8  static=1
INFO [07-08|10:27:51.287] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=5  static=1
INFO [07-08|10:27:55.181] Deep froze chain segment                 blocks=2     elapsed=133.622ms   number=8,807,987 hash=23cfa7..830fa8
INFO [07-08|10:28:01.288] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=7  static=1
INFO [07-08|10:28:11.288] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=7  static=1
INFO [07-08|10:28:21.289] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=6  static=1
INFO [07-08|10:28:31.292] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=6  static=1
INFO [07-08|10:28:41.293] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=5  static=1
INFO [07-08|10:28:51.294] Looking for peers                        peercount=2 tried=8  static=1
INFO [07-08|10:29:01.295] Looking for peers                        peercount=2 tried=4  static=1
INFO [07-08|10:29:11.294] Looking for peers                        peercount=2 tried=6  static=1
INFO [07-08|10:29:21.296] Looking for peers                        peercount=2 tried=6  static=1
INFO [07-08|10:29:31.296] Looking for peers                        peercount=2 tried=6  static=1
INFO [07-08|10:29:41.302] Looking for peers                        peercount=2 tried=5  static=1
INFO [07-08|10:29:51.304] Looking for peers                        peercount=2 tried=6  static=1
INFO [07-08|10:30:01.307] Looking for peers                        peercount=2 tried=7  static=1
INFO [07-08|10:30:11.309] Looking for peers                        peercount=2 tried=5  static=1
INFO [07-08|10:30:21.311] Looking for peers                        peercount=2 tried=6  static=1
INFO [07-08|10:30:31.311] Looking for peers                        peercount=2 tried=5  static=1
INFO [07-08|10:30:41.311] Looking for peers                        peercount=2 tried=6  static=1
INFO [07-08|10:30:51.313] Looking for peers                        peercount=2 tried=8  static=1
INFO [07-08|10:31:01.314] Looking for peers                        peercount=2 tried=6  static=1
INFO [07-08|11:13:29.673] Writing clean trie cache to disk         path=/Users/user/Library/Ethereum/rinkeby/geth/triecache threads=1
INFO [07-08|11:13:29.675] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [07-08|11:13:32.926] Persisted the clean trie cache           path=/Users/user/Library/Ethereum/rinkeby/geth/triecache elapsed=3.251s
INFO [07-08|12:13:29.760] Writing clean trie cache to disk         path=/Users/user/Library/Ethereum/rinkeby/geth/triecache threads=1
INFO [07-08|12:13:29.763] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [07-08|12:13:32.399] Persisted the clean trie cache           path=/Users/user/Library/Ethereum/rinkeby/geth/triecache elapsed=2.635s
INFO [07-08|13:13:29.731] Writing clean trie cache to disk         path=/Users/user/Library/Ethereum/rinkeby/geth/triecache threads=1
INFO [07-08|13:13:29.735] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [07-08|13:13:31.269] Persisted the clean trie cache           path=/Users/user/Library/Ethereum/rinkeby/geth/triecache elapsed=1.538s
INFO [07-08|14:13:29.835] Writing clean trie cache to disk         path=/Users/user/Library/Ethereum/rinkeby/geth/triecache threads=1
INFO [07-08|14:13:29.853] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [07-08|14:13:33.823] Persisted the clean trie cache           path=/Users/user/Library/Ethereum/rinkeby/geth/triecache elapsed=3.980s
INFO [07-08|15:13:29.795] Writing clean trie cache to disk         path=/Users/user/Library/Ethereum/rinkeby/geth/triecache threads=1
INFO [07-08|15:13:29.799] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [07-08|15:13:32.508] Persisted the clean trie cache           path=/Users/user/Library/Ethereum/rinkeby/geth/triecache elapsed=2.712s
INFO [07-08|16:13:29.927] Writing clean trie cache to disk         path=/Users/user/Library/Ethereum/rinkeby/geth/triecache threads=1
INFO [07-08|16:13:29.928] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [07-08|16:13:32.662] Persisted the clean trie cache           path=/Users/user/Library/Ethereum/rinkeby/geth/triecache elapsed=2.734s
```

As the log says, it worked fine, but suddenly it stopped receiving blocks from other peers, and stuck with `Looking for peers`. And then, following three logs were repeating.

```
INFO [07-08|11:13:29.673] Writing clean trie cache to disk         path=/Users/user/Library/Ethereum/rinkeby/geth/triecache threads=1
INFO [07-08|11:13:29.675] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [07-08|11:13:32.926] Persisted the clean trie cache           path=/Users/user/Library/Ethereum/rinkeby/geth/triecache elapsed=3.251s
```

So I tried restarting Geth. (I just killed the process and entered the geth command as above.) But then, it didn't get syncing or receiving blocks again. The log just shows `Looking for peers` permanently. The node already had peers but not syncing. The log looks like below.

```
...
INFO [07-08|16:38:37.212] IPC endpoint opened                      url=/Users/user/Library/Ethereum/rinkeby/geth.ipc
INFO [07-08|16:38:37.213] HTTP server started                      endpoint=[::]:8545 prefix= cors= vhosts=localhost
INFO [07-08|16:38:37.213] WebSocket enabled                        url=ws://[::]:8546
INFO [07-08|16:38:48.095] New local node record                    seq=287 id=9f26334289445bf1 ip=<my ipaddress> udp=30303 tcp=30303
INFO [07-08|16:38:48.216] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=34 static=0
INFO [07-08|16:38:58.218] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=30 static=0
INFO [07-08|16:39:08.286] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=35 static=0
INFO [07-08|16:39:18.546] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=27 static=0
INFO [07-08|16:39:28.552] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=36 static=1
INFO [07-08|16:39:38.557] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=33 static=1
INFO [07-08|16:39:48.879] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=25 static=1
INFO [07-08|16:39:59.144] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=33 static=1
INFO [07-08|16:40:09.211] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=35 static=1
INFO [07-08|16:40:19.214] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=31 static=1
INFO [07-08|16:40:29.531] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=22 static=1
INFO [07-08|16:40:39.547] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=33 static=1
INFO [07-08|16:40:49.878] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=27 static=1
INFO [07-08|16:41:00.212] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=37 static=1
INFO [07-08|16:41:10.215] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=25 static=1
INFO [07-08|16:41:20.216] Looking for peers                        peercount=1 tried=20 static=1
...
```

So here is my questions.

1. Why Geth has stucked suddenly?
2. Why Geth doesn't work after restarting it?
3. Is there a way to restart Geth gracefully? I just killed process and started Geth again with the command I used, but I always had to erase leveldb when restarting Geth like this way.

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I restarted Geth with `verbosity 4` (DEBUG mode), and attached the logs between `INFO Looking for peers` logs. DEBUG logs looks like below.

```
...
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:23.173] Revalidated node                         b=4  id=9f2cb42ade264eea checks=1
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:23.178] Adding p2p peer                          peercount=3 id=8391c2401d336e64 conn=dyndial    addr=112.194.96.138:8502   name=OpenEthereum/v3.2.6-...
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:23.306] Ethereum handshake failed                id=7b3f212e39a05d39 conn=dyndial    err="fork ID rejected: remote needs update"
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:23.306] Removing p2p peer                        peercount=2 id=7b3f212e39a05d39 duration=147.554ms   req=true  err="subprotocol error"
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:23.335] Adding p2p peer                          peercount=3 id=84e07faffaf52840 conn=dyndial    addr=52.169.42.101:30303   name=Geth/v1.10.5-unstabl...
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:23.563] Ethereum handshake failed                id=84e07faffaf52840 conn=dyndial    err=EOF
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:23.563] Message handling failed in `snap`        peer=84e07faf err=EOF
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:23.563] Removing p2p peer                        peercount=2 id=84e07faffaf52840 duration=227.601ms   req=true  err="subprotocol error"
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:23.827] Recalculated downloader QoS values       rtt=20s confidence=1.000 ttl=1m0s
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:24.441] Adding p2p peer                          peercount=3 id=8ecc16f9400d6fc4 conn=dyndial    addr=63.34.52.202:33333    name=Geth/v1.9.24-stable-...
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:24.720] Ethereum handshake failed                id=8ecc16f9400d6fc4 conn=dyndial    err="network ID mismatch: 219913 (!= 4)"
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:24.721] Removing p2p peer                        peercount=2 id=8ecc16f9400d6fc4 duration=280.038ms   req=false err="network ID mismatch: 219913 (!= 4)"
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:25.729] Revalidated node                         b=7  id=9f4e2c6ea7153f79 checks=1
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:25.764] Adding p2p peer                          peercount=3 id=0e10a37bbbc33e44 conn=dyndial    addr=15.236.32.166:30303   name=Geth/v1.10.5-unstabl...
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:26.039] Ethereum handshake failed                id=0e10a37bbbc33e44 conn=dyndial    err="fork ID rejected: local incompatible or needs update"
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:26.039] Message handling failed in `snap`        peer=0e10a37b err=EOF
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:26.039] Removing p2p peer                        peercount=2 id=0e10a37bbbc33e44 duration=275.341ms   req=true  err="subprotocol error"
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:26.612] Adding p2p peer                          peercount=3 id=8ec7352b8985509b conn=dyndial    addr=159.65.254.146:30303  name=bor/v1.10.1-stable-1...
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:26.811] Ethereum handshake failed                id=8ec7352b8985509b conn=dyndial    err="network ID mismatch: 137 (!= 4)"
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:26.811] Removing p2p peer                        peercount=2 id=8ec7352b8985509b duration=198.985ms   req=false err="network ID mismatch: 137 (!= 4)"
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:27.843] Adding p2p peer                          peercount=3 id=8ec75fa18296fa0c conn=dyndial    addr=104.209.34.240:30306  name=Geth/validator4/v1.9...
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:27.975] Ethereum handshake failed                id=8ec75fa18296fa0c conn=dyndial    err="network ID mismatch: 1337 (!= 4)"
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:27.975] Removing p2p peer                        peercount=2 id=8ec75fa18296fa0c duration=132.793ms   req=false err="network ID mismatch: 1337 (!= 4)"
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:28.179] Ethereum handshake failed                id=8391c2401d336e64 conn=dyndial    err="read timeout"
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:28.179] Removing p2p peer                        peercount=1 id=8391c2401d336e64 duration=5.000s      req=false err="read timeout"
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:31.793] Adding p2p peer                          peercount=2 id=8ed611401e2afc34 conn=dyndial    addr=34.195.70.235:30303   name=besu/v21.1.7/linux-x...
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:31.793] Ethereum handshake failed                id=8ed611401e2afc34 conn=dyndial    err="network ID mismatch: 11297108109 (!= 4)"
DEBUG[07-15|09:48:31.793] Removing p2p peer                        peercount=1 id=8ed611401e2afc34 duration="406.245µs" req=false err="network ID mismatch: 11297108109 (!= 4)"
...
```

The logs say `Ethereum handshake failed`. How could I fix this issue? Is Geth has to be turned on always after first time syncing? Why restarting Geth destroys `Ethereum handshake`?

Comment: add `verbosity 8` flag and come back with more logs. looks like network issue, firewall or something, but could be that you have got a wrong head block and nobody links to you because you are in a wrong chain. more verbose log would show it

Comment: if you are using `geth` from `master` branch on github you can killl geth with -9 with no problem. they just fixed a nasty bug (issue 22728 on github) that corrupted the chain, a few weeks ago, but this is only available on master branch

Comment: @Nulik I've erased leveldb and restarted geth, it was fine at first time. But when my Macbook turned off because of out of battery (I was outside for a while) so when I turned it on after few hours later and restarted geth, geth works weird like my question again. So I restarted geth with `verbosity 4` (DEBUG logs, when I looked at man page, verbosity was up to 5 and 5 was TRACE mode and it's logs were too many, so I used 4 mode), and updated my question with the logs between `INFO Looking for peers` logs. Could you see it again please? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what was the reason for this issue for my case. I was using Geth version `1.10.3-stable`. So I looked for the new releases at go-ethereum github page that if new versions solving the issue like this. And there were two new stable releases. And `1.10.4-stable` version said that

> Geth v1.10.4 is a feature release and adds compatibility with the upcoming London hard fork.

So there was a hard fork after `1.10.3-stable` version released. And at **Additional notes about the London changes** section, it said

> This release contains testnet activation block numbers for the London hard fork. The numbers are: Ropsten - 10499401, Goerli - 5062605, Rinkeby - 8897988. (#23041)

So I looked at my DEBUG logs.
At some DEBUG logs, I've found this log.

```
DEBUG[07-15|10:49:42.932] Ancient blocks frozen already            number=8,897,987 hash=d2df74..48ba4e frozen=8,807,988
```

It looked like my Geth node got stuck because it reached the last block right before the hard fork. So I updated Geth to `1.10.5-stable` and restarted Geth. And now Geth is importing new blocks fine now.

**Conclusion**

My case was because of the hard fork. When I upgraded Geth to newly released version, now it's receiving blocks fine which created after the hard fork.